# ChromeOS Flex on MacBookPro 16" late 2019 with no mouse cursor

Tags: mouse, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, macbookpro

I installed ChromeOS Flex through the Chromebook Recovery Utility 0.2.2 on an USB pen drive and now it boots well on my MacBookPro 16" late 2019 (with Sonoma). But at the first panel I can't click on the button "Get Started" because the mouse cursor is not visible and the keyboard doesn't work at all. Is any workaround to fix the trouble?

Also, if everything worked well, could I build and release Google Kiosk PAW apps on my MacBookPro?